# Search String array for String

Tags: java, arrays

I want a command such as this:

`setstat <statname> <level>`

However, my 'statname's are in a Array; and I need to output the Array number.
This is the code I am using:

---

```
String[] statname = {"att", "def", "str", "hp",
                     "ranged", "pray", "magic", "cooking", 
                     "wc", "fletch", "fish", "fm", 
                     "craft", "smith", "mining", "herb", 
                     "agil", "thieving", "slayer", "farming", "rc"};

int statid = statname.contains(arg[1]);
```

---

However, it doesn't work (for me). Seeing as `contains(...)` isn't compatible with an `String[]` array.

I have no idea which method to use, or how to handle this.

Comment: You may want to use an `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Arrays.asList(statname).indexOf(arg[1]);` to find the index of an item.

Answer (score 0):

Since your array is not ordered, this function will work:

```
public int getFoundIndex(String[] stringArr_toSearch, String str_toFind)
   for(int i = 0; i < stringArr_toSearch.length; i++)  {
      if(stringArr_toSearch[i].equals(str_toFind))  {
         return  i;
      }
   }
   return  -1;
}
```

Call it with

```
int foundIdx = getFoundIndex(statName, "str");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat code for the linear search which returns the index of the element in the array if the element is found, else returns false.

```
public int search(String[] array, String element)
{
  if(array == null || element == null)
    return -1;

  for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  {
    if(array[i].equals(element))
      return i;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Using the approach: `Arrays.asList(statname).indexOf(arg[1);` can get expensive, if you have to search for the elements a lot of time.

You can sort your array once, and then do a binary search too, in order to achieve faster lookup times, if you have to search for elements in the `statname` array multiple times.